# Axway cluster based deployment

Tags: api-gateway

I have to install an axway api gateway in such a way that the group would be on one ec2-instance and the one gateway each  on the other 2 ec2-instances.when i try to install i dont see the option for cluster architecture while manually deploying the axway api gateway package.Any idea if thats how it is or if this can be achieved even without that option during installation?